# With GWT, is there a way to not load widgets declared in uibinder xml files?

Tags: gwt, gwt2, uibinder

One common design I have with GWT is to create a widget which contains two children: A and B.

I declare these two widgets A and B in the uibinder file associated to my main widget.

What I want to do is to load or not widget A depending on an if statement.

Ideal approach is to set provided=true for widget A and to set widget A to null when I want to not load this widget. But GWT throws an error.

Is there a way to declare widgets in uibinder and then not loading them ?

thanks

**EDIT: after a lot of discussions, an ideal approach is to declared a field "provided=true" and "optional=true" when optional=true, createAndBindUI must not throw an Exception if the field is null. This is a clean approach.**

**If you think that this feature must exists in GWT, please star this issue:
http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=5699**

**EDIT 2 : using the LazyPanel as described by Thomas seems to be a better way to handle this.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I stumbled on the GWT issue, which led me here, so here's my take on it, 20 months later.

Use a `LazyPanel` and set it to `visible="false"` so that it's content is not built until you need it (simply call `setVisible(true)` to reveal it, triggerring the lazy-initialization of its content.

`LazyPanel` is fully integrated with UiBinder so that you declare its content in the same UiBinder template, as if it were a `SimplePanel`, without even bothering creating a subclass of `LazyPanel`. See https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/2.4/DevGuideUiBinder#Lazy

Comment: yep, seems to be an excellent way to do it. I think this is the best approach. 20 months later, I update my vote ;) (Thomas, you are the winner on most of my answers about gwt, if you come to Montpellier one of these days, let me know, I'll pay you a drink !)

Comment: Note that I haven't tried it with a `@UiField(provided=true)` widget in the content, and this isn't unit-tested either.

Comment: @ThomasBroyer, why does LazyPanel allow only a single child? I don't see any reason for it not to have multiple children. Now I have to wrap children with `SimplePanel` and it makes layout too clumsy.

Answer (score 1):

I would revert the logic. If you don't need the widget remove it

```
widget.removeFromParent();
```

I think it's a cleaner approach, since the UIBinder automatically defines and creates them.

Comment: I thought of this solution but there is performance problem: instanciate and remove widget: two DOM manipulations. Another problem is that if I need to provide the widget by provided=true if the constructor is not empty and in one case I don't want to provide this (I don't know what instance to provide)

Answer (score 1):

Since conditionals are not allowed in a UiBinder XML I'd suggest you define **placeholders** (i.e., panels) in your `ui.xml`, have a reference to them in your view class and decide there whether a specific widget needs to be created and added or not.

This is a common approach when using MVP pattern with nested presenters.

EDIT:

Until your request has been implemented by the GWT developers you could extend the `FlowPanel` and overwrite the `add(Widget)` method to check for `null` as in:

```
public class ExtendedFlowPanel extends FlowPanel {

    public ExtendedFlowPanel() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void add(Widget w) {
        if (w != null) {
            super.add(w);
        }
    }
}
```

This way you can use `provided = true` and pass `null` to the panel.

Comment: the problem with this solution is we can't use the simple handler definition and we can't design the widget in uibinder

Comment: For simple event handlers: there I see no solution except doing it the 'old' way (which still works great :)). For the styling: do it in code (is a pain, I know) or style the widget (those parts that are reusable) in its UiBinder XML. Or isn't that possible?

Comment: ...oooor (just an idea): create a new `Composite` containing those two widgets A and B and let it decide what to show when and how...

Comment: no, I can't do it, because this is an example, this is not always the same widget A and B ;) But good try ! I think I will open an issue in GWT to provide a good and clean solution for this problem (for example, if provided=true return a null widget, do not load it)

Comment: lol I was thinking you want a vote up ;) So I ask a vote up too ! My english is not fluent, so sometimes I don't understand well ;)

Comment: :) no not really. I think the question is good and I'm trying to help finding a valid solution. Is the extended flow panel of any use? It worked in my small example.

Comment: That's a simple and clean solution. I would love it if it runs ;) And this is not the case. I've got an error which is: 
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.myCompany_MyModuleUiBinderImpl.createAndBindUi(MyModuleUiBinderImpl.java:34)

Comment: Give me some minutes. I'm currently on the iphone on which coding isn't that much of fun :). I'll post my example.

Comment: Ok, I think I know what you've done: with really simple widgets it runs, but when this widget has a property or children, it does not run. Try your example by adding Label with text in your ExtendedFlowPanel. It will not run, isn't it ? The cause is that the uibinder tries to set property or add children on a null instance

Comment: Do your widgets share a common interface or superclass? I'm thinking about a 'dummy' implementation rendering minimal markup.

Comment: No not really, these inherit Composite class. I think I will use the suggestion of Carlos but just configure them with visible false and not removing them (which is more CPU intensive I think)

Comment: Ok. Guess that's a not too bad compromise. Please post the link when you've filled in an issue for the GWT dev team.